# get geolocation not working with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

I have used below code :

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(GetCoords, fail);

function GetCoords(position) {
  alert("3");
  document.getElementById("latitudetag").innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
  document.getElementById("longitudetag").innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;
}

function fail() {
  alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
}
```

it always redirect me in fail function and I am not able to get lat long of current location.
can anyone help me to resolve it ?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: refer this https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: where are you testing it? You know that geolocation only works on `HTTPS`

Comment: yes ,you are right it is only work on https .